# Backbone.relational, real-time and handling large data

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, socket.io, backbone-relational

I'm building a real-time feed application using Backbone.js, node.js and socket.io.

My `Feed` is a collection of `Update` models. Displaying these, overriding `Backbone.sync` for integration with `socket.io` works fine.

The complication comes in that each `Update` has a set of comments associated with it. When I show each `Update` in the `Feed` view, I want to show a summary of the associated comments (number of comments and a single 'most poular' comment), and also have the ability to click through to a different view to display each `Update` on its own with a paginated list of comments with further data.

I'm using `backbone-relational` to model the relationship between the `Update` model and `Comment` model, as follows:

`Feed (collection) -> Update (model) -(has many)-> Comment (model)`

I've been following this `backbone-relational` tutorial, but it seems to assume that I'd want to have all related data in memory at once in my `Feed` view, which I don't as there are potentially thousands of comments updating in real-time:

http://antoviaque.org/docs/tutorials/backbone-relational-tutorial/

My questions are:

1. How can I bring in summary data for comments to each `Update` in my `Feed` view without loading all comment data, and also maintain the ability to show paginated full data in my `Update` view?
2. I'm using `backbone.layoutmanager` for rendering my views. How best should I break my views up to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1):

For Q1:

- I'm assuming you're using something like [ioSync](https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind) to use socket.io in Backbone.sync instead of REST API, or a similar solution.
- Include metadata (such as # of comments) as an attribute on `Update`. If your `Update` object is heavy weight in itself, you could update the count using [ioBind](https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind) and custom server-side socket.io events instead of sending the whole object every time.
- Include an attribute `topComment` as an additional one-to-one relation in `Update`. When initially loading `Update` from the server, include `topComment` in the response, but not the other comments.
- Lazy-load the rest of the comments using custom socket.io events. You will likely want a server-side handler that takes as parameters `updateId`, `startIndex`, `maxComments`, which returns a list of comments for the given `Update` starting at the given index. If the result is sent to the client as JSON, then it's easy to do something like this on the client:

  ```
  // Assume `model` is an instance of `Update`.
  socket.emit('get_comments_page', {
    updateId: model.get('id'),
    startIndex: 1,
    maxComments: 10
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      alert('Unable to fetch comments: ', err);
    } else {
      model.get('messages').reset(data)
    }
  });
  ```
- Avoid sending ID for all comments when fetching `Update` then trying to use `fetchRelated` to resolve them. I learned this one the hard way :O/
- You could also store the comments collection directly on the view without associating it as relationship of `Update`

For Q2:

I don't have any experience with `layoutmanager` as I use [Backbone.Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette) for managing my views. Marionette has an [async extension](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette.async) (disclaimer: I'm a co-maintainer). I encourage to see how Marionette.async does the delayed rendering, waiting for the data to arrive from the server.

The main idea is to use jquery's Deferred objects that resolve when the data comes back from the server. Extending the above example with deferred:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // ... normal stuff that views need ...
  initialize: function() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    // Assume `model` is an instance of `Update`.
    var that = this;
    socket.emit('get_comments_page', {
      updateId: that.model.get('id'),
      startIndex: that.options.pageNumber,
      maxComments: 10
    }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        alert('Unable to fetch comments: ', err);
      } else {
        that.model.get('messages').reset(data)
      }
      deferred.resolve();
    });
    this.promise = deferred.promise();
  },

  render: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.promise.done(function() {
      // Do your normal rendering code here, for instance:
      $(that.el).html(that.template(that.model.toJSON()));
    });
    return this;
  }
});
```

Note: the code snippets above are not tested as is.